# Футер в HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать футер таким, как, например, на сайте stackoverflow, т.е таким:
[image: Footer на stackoverflow]

Однако, когда пытаюсь его сделать я, получается вот так:

[image: Footer у меня]

HTML

```
<footer>
        <a>Random names</a>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    background-color: #282828;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Вопрос: как сделать футер нормальным, т.е без пробелов от начала страницы и начала футера?

Comment: body{margin:0;}

Comment: Судя по всему вы не обнулили стандартные стили браузеров, лучше всего для этих целей использовать reset css или normalize css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите для `body` свойство `margin` со значением 0

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```